# Failed to create table: entity was of unexpected kind BigQuery Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I exported my Firebase data to Google cloud storage and I try to see tables detail in BigQuery. When I selected my bucket, I'm getting a failed job error

> Failed to create table: Entity "89jHDLF6AkEpTWo3TGx0" was of unexpected kind "book"

Is there anyone who knows how to solve it?

Note: I download file from bucket but file is encrypted bt google-manager. Also it works for me if I can see file details without encrypt

I selected bucket from from cloud storage for create table in BigQuery.

I expected to see table details.